# How to use DataContractJsonSerializer for Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have json structure like this:

```
{
   "id":"12345",
   "first_name": "dino",
   "last_name": "he",
   "emails": {
      "preferred": "1",
      "personal": "2",
      "business": "3",
      "other": "4"
   }
}
```

I want to get the value in Emails
So I write two class:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserInformation
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "emails")]
    public Emails emails { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
[DataContract]
public class Emails
{
    [DataMember(Name = "preferred")]
    public string Preferred { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Name = "personal")]
    public string Account { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "business")]
    public string Personal { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "other")]
    public string Business { get; set; }
}
```

And 
I write code like this:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ASP.net\WebApplication1\WebApplication2\TextFile1.txt");
string text = stream.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(byteArray);


DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserInformation));
var info = serializer.ReadObject(stream1) as UserInformation;
stream1.Close();
```

For info, I can get other value in UserInformation, But for Emails I get nothing.
Why, And how should I write the class?
Please help me!

Comment: What do you mean you get nothing? Isn't there any value in `info.emails`? Are you sure you are reading the right file?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure and the problem is I need to change the property in Emails to lower case!
I don't know why... but seems like I change them to lower case, they could work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem is I need to change all my property in Emails to lower case...
I don't know why.. But it worked.

Comment: It's because you do this: `[DataMember(Name = "emails")]
    public Emails emails { get; set; }`. Without the Name parameter being specified, it would default to accepting `Emails`.

Answer (score 1):

The case of your object property must match the case in the JSON.  (See bold below).

```
public Emails **emails** { get; set; }

{ "id":"12345", "first_name": "dino", "last_name": "he", "**emails**": { "preferred": "1", "personal": "2", "business": "3", "other": "4" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add Name to DataContract attribute as you did for DataMember:

```
[DataContract (Name="emails")]
public class Emails
{
```