# How to update JSON data object in the isolated storage of my Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net, isolatedstorage

I have listpicker Item which contain list of expense.
On clicking it, an new XAML page is opened and details of expense is obtained.
There is an option to edit and save.

So how should I update that particular JSON data object which is stored in isolated storage when user clicks update button.

My code is here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=83F2A501543779D4%211229

Thank you

Here is the code in the UPDATEXPENSES.XAML.CS. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

**After Navigation to this page**

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e){

```
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        String dataFromAppSettings;
        ExpencesGroup data;

        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedExpenceObject", out selectedIndex);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("TypeofTransaction", out TransactionType);
        if (TransactionType == ExpencesModel.ExpencesGivenKey)
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(ExpencesModel.ExpencesGivenKey, out dataFromAppSettings))
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpencesGroup>(dataFromAppSettings);

                if (data != null) {
                    thisExpence = data.Expences[Convert.ToInt32(selectedIndex)];
                    this.DataContext = thisExpence;
                    SwitchBetweenListItems(thisExpence.TypeofTransaction);
                    SwitchBetweenListItems(thisExpence.PaidThrough);
                }
            }
        }


        else
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(ExpencesModel.ExpencesTakenKey, out dataFromAppSettings))
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpencesGroup>(dataFromAppSettings);
                if (data != null) {
                    thisExpence = data.Expences[Convert.ToInt32(selectedIndex)];
                    this.DataContext = thisExpence;
                    SwitchBetweenListItems(thisExpence.TypeofTransaction);
                    SwitchBetweenListItems(thisExpence.PaidThrough);

                }
            }
        }
```

**After clicking update button**

```
    private void update_Expense(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        thisExpence.Amount = amount.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(thisExpence.Amount.ToString());
        thisExpence.ExpenseTitle = ExpenseName.Text;
        ListPickerItem PaidThroughListPicker = (ListPickerItem)paidThrough.SelectedItem;
        thisExpence.PaidThrough = (String)PaidThroughListPicker.Content;
        thisExpence.expenceStatus = (bool)PaymentStatus.IsChecked;
        ListPickerItem listPickerItem = (ListPickerItem)TypeofTransaction.SelectedItem;
        thisExpence.TypeofTransaction = (String)listPickerItem.Content;
        if (thisExpence.TypeofTransaction == ExpencesModel.ExpencesGivenKey)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Given);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[ExpencesModel.ExpencesGivenKey] = data;
        }
        else
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Taken);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[ExpencesModel.ExpencesTakenKey]. = data;
        }
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ExpencesPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at these examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx?

Comment: Hi verdesrobert,Thank you for your response. Yes I have tried it. I am having complex list object to be updated. So I couldn't use it. Can you go through my code once and check where I am going wrong. This particular piece of code is in updateExpenses.xaml.cs file.

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of code that minimally reproduce the problem you're having rather than linking to a temporary file location.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: sure. I have put the code below this.

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down? I don't understand what your code is trying to do so I can't tell you what might be wrong. What exactly isn't working as expected? You're serializing `App.ViewModel.Given` for example. Is that not what you want?

Comment: On clicking the update button, I am getting all the form elements. thiseExpence refers to the item that an user clicked. It is initialized after the navigating this particular(updateExpense.xaml) page. I serialized the date and gave IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save() to save the data object. The updated values are not being saved.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Is the information provided above enough?

Comment: Does the `Given` property reference the same object you want to serialize?

Comment: Given refers to the whole object. I have set current object with updated values, searilizing whole object and saving the whole object again. If this is the cause for problem, How should I save current object permanently to isolated store?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: is that clear?

Comment: It's not entirely clear. There's too much there still and it's not obvious your code is saving the right objects.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: okie..Thank you for your support. So how should I proceed on this?

Comment: Step through your code and debug it? Comment out blocks to help narrow the scope of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You can read the `JSON` data object from `IsolatedStorage` and convert it to a `DataContract` using `datacontractjsonserializer`. Then you can update the particular value on your button click.

Step 2: Then convert back this DataContract to stream or Json Data Object and store it to IsolatedStorage.

You can refer [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959698/how-to-use-datacontractjsonserializer-for-json) for step 1. Refer [How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also

Comment: Hi, Vasuy, Thanks for your response. I have used JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Given) to serialize object. I got the details of particular data object that an user has clicked. I have set the data. But the object is not getting updated. can you go through the code in updateExpenses.xaml.cs page and let me know where I did mistake. I have commented the code since it was not working. Thank you